# How to update the users database record when made paypal payment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, paypal

Wondering if someone can at least point me in the right direction? I have developed a website using node.js that has a mongodb database. Currently users are able to register/login and a session is maintained which allows them to navigate around the site but with some content being restricted to paid users.

Currently I have got this working for users that are logged in compared to those who are not logged in. What I want to do is change this to users that are logged in and who have paid for membership.

Can someone point me in the right direction. I want users to have the choice of becoming members by paying via paypal and somehow I need to be notified of the successful payment that will change a 'member' variable on the users database record so that I know they are now members. I will then use this variable to give them access to the restricted website content using middleware.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell me what you are using to save session of users? is it passport??? I might be able to help you after you give me this info. Also, do tell how you are differentiating between logged-in and guest users

Comment: Hi Ravi, 

I am using passport.

My full list of dependencies are:
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.2.1"

Currently I have videos on my website that can only be accessed if the user is logged in. I do this by placing some middleware (to check the user is logged in) which is placed on the route that shows the video. 

Thanks!